# How to populate cell when multiple cells are all true

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have an Excel file with Zeros (0 = No) and Ones (1 = Yes) in columns L thru V. Depending on what their answers are in those columns, I want to put some text in column Z. For instance:

```
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

If all of those cells are 0, put "Beginner" in Z

```
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

would be "Learner" -- all the way through:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

would be "Expert".

I tried different variations of IF-THEN-ELSE and the SELECT CASE function but I can't seem to get anything to work right. I know that I'm going to have to loop through the rows (there are about 500) but how do I tell Excel what I want?

Forgot to mention, data could also look like this

```
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

I've got about 50 different scenarios that show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the answers into a string and choose your output based on that.

```
For r = 1 To 500
Answers = ""

For c = 12 To 22
    Answers = Answers & Cells(r, c)
Next c

Select Case Answers
    Case "00000000000"
        Cells(r, 26) = "Beginner"
    Case "10000000000"
        Cells(r, 26) = "Learner"
    Case "11110000000"
        Cells(r, 26) = "Sophomore"
    Case "11111111111"
        Cells(r, 26) = "Expert"
    Case Else
        Cells(r, 26) = "<something else>"
End Select

Next r
```

Edit:
Depending on how complex your rules are, you may be better off using if-then-elseif-else, because then you can use the Like operator, which lets you use wildcards.

```
If Answers = "00000000000" Then
    output = "Beginner"
ElseIf Answers = "11111111111" Then
    output = "Expert"
ElseIf Answers Like "1111*" Then
    output = "Sophomore"
Else
    output = "other"
End If
```

Comment: This (the first piece of code) is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't figure it out. If I run out of code room, I'll create another subroutine and call it from the previous one. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM to sum up all the rows. Then post your answer based on the range the sum fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CHOOSE` function on the `SUM`, which will return a number between 1-11 that will pick from your list of names.  Fill in the numbers below for your categories:

```
=CHOOSE(SUM(L2:V2), "Beginner", "Learner", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Expert")
```

Then copy the formula down through all of the rows.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using a formula but it's not just the sum of rows. I could have 1's in the first 4 columns or the last 4 columns -- they both SUM to 4. But 1's in the first 4 columns means the person was a 'Sophomore' and 1's in the last 4 columns means they started at 'Silver' and are now an 'Expert'.

Answer (score 0):

If the total sum of 1s is what matters then you could just do:

```
For Each rw in Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows
  Select Case Application.Sum(rw.Columns("L:V"))
    Case 0
      rs.Cells(1,26) = "Beginner"
    Case 1
      rs.Cells(1,26) = "Learner"
    Case 11
      rs.Cells(1,26) = "Expert"
  End Select
Next rw
```

If 1s in specific places matter, then this code will work:

```
Sub FillZ()

Dim wRange As Range
Dim resultArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set wRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)

resultArray = SpecialConcatenate(workingRange)

For i = 1 To wRange.Rows.Count
  Select Case resultArray(i)
    Case "00000000000"
      wRange(i, 26) = "Beginner"
    Case "10000000000"
      wRange(i, 26) = "Learner"
    Case "11111111111"
      wRange(i, 26) = "Expert"
  End Select
Next i

End Sub

Function SpecialConcatenate(wRange As Range) As Variant

Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim resultArray() As Variant

ReDim resultArray(1 To wRange.Rows.Count)

For j = 1 To wRange.Rows.Count
  resultArray(j) = ""
  For k = 1 To 11
    resultArray(j) = resultArray(j) & wRange.Cells(j, k + 11).Value
  Next k
Next j
SpecialConcatenate = resultArray

End Function
```

Comment: I tried something like that but it matters WHERE the 1's are, not just how many of them there are.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, ok, worked up one that will do that for you, it'd actually be nicer converting to hex, but this should work fine.